# Objective-C /NSObject pointers compared to C pointers

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, pointers

According to apples objective-c documentation, the NSObjects use C-pointers to keep track of them. I am fairly new to iOS and comparing the pointer operations on NSObjects with C pointers gets confusing.
For example:

```
NSString *string1 = @"This is a string";
NSString *string2;
string2 = string 1;
```

In C, (correct me if I am wrong please) this = b/w 2 pointers makes them point to the same "pointee". This means that changing string1 should also change string2. But it doesn't seem to work like this, and NSStrings are strictly immutable anyways so this adds a bit of confusion.

```
string1 = @"new string";
```

If these pointers operate like C pointers, than shouldn't this change string2 since it points to the same place as string1. Also, in C, a pointer must be assigned to a pointee before it can be dereferenced. This rule does not seem to apply to NSObjects. What is the '@' doing? Finally, why don't I ever see dereferencing with NSObjects happening like:

```
*string1 = @"modifying the string"; //shouldn't this be how to access the contents of the pointer string1 if it operates like a c pointer?
```

Could someone shed some light on what is going on under the hood of Objective-C pointers and how they compare and contrast to C pointers? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Changing a `const char []` which a string literal is is undefined behaviour in C (and I'm very sure in Objective-C, too). So what is the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would get the same behavior in C as in Objective-C: if you do this

```
char *a = "hello";
char *b = a;
b = "world";
```

then `a` is not going to change. The changes made to a common object pointed to by multiple pointers become visible when the object is *mutable*. Neither `NSString` nor C string literals are mutable, so let's construct a different example:

```
NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString string:@"This is a string"];
NSMutableString *string2;
string2 = string1;
NSLog(string1);
NSLog(string2);
[string1 appendString:@" (a very long one!)"];
NSLog(string1);
NSLog(string2);
```

Now `string2` "sees" the changes made to `string1`, because the object is mutable.

A similar example in C would look like this:

```
char[] a = "hello";
char b = a;
printf("%s %s\n", a, b);
strcpy(b, "world");
printf("%s %s\n", a, b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C pointers don't "operate like C pointers", the ARE C pointers.

Objects in Objective-C are always stack based. Under the covers, the space for the object is created by a call to the C function calloc (or something very similar).

The `@` in the expression

```
NSString *aString = @"this is a string";
```

is basically syntactic sugar that defines a new immutable NSString constant defined at compile time.

The code

```
NSString *string1 = @"This is a string";
NSString *string2;
string2 = string1;
```

Does in fact cause both string1 and string2 to point to the same memory address.

@dasblinkenlight's excellent answer (voted) shows you how to use mutable strings to illustrate changing 1 string that is pointed to in 2 places and then seeing the results reflected in both of those places.

Comment: thanks, so what is happening, then when i set string1 to something different like str1 = @"this is a different string"; does this create a new string object and change where string 1 points to? because if they point to the same place in memory, then changing str1 should change str2, i guess the immutalbe NSStrings behave differently

Comment: Yes. The @"" construct creates a new static NSString object at compile time. `str1 = @"this is a different string"` points `str` to a newly defined string. You can log the address of an object by casting it to an unsigned long and using the "%X" format string in an NSLog. I suggest doing some tests where you log the addresses of strings as you do assignments to see what's happening.